# I upgraded to rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2 and user login broke

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

After upgrading to Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.2 I get the following error:

[image: Console error]

Pointing to the following code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    if params[:new_registration]
      redirect_to new_user_url
    else
      if user
        if user.email_confirmed?
          if params[:remember_me]
            cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token          
          else
            cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
          end
          flash[:notice] = t('sessions_controller.flash.logged_in')
          if session[:url]
            redirect_to session[:url]
            session.delete :url
          else
            redirect_to root_url
          end
        else
          user.send_email_confirmation
          flash[:notice] = t('sessions_controller.flash.message')
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      else
        flash[:error] = t('sessions_controller.flash.invalid')
        redirect_to new_password_reset_url
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    flash[:notice] = t('sessions_controller.flash.logged_out')
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Any suggestion why this may be failing going up a version, Things were working in 4.1.8?

Also when I go to production I get this error in the nginx log file:

passenger_native_support.so: undefined symbol: rb_thread_blocking_region

It is discussed here:
https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1314

I am wondering if this is related?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, which I solved by upgrading gems also to the most recent versions.

I documented here: [solved incident](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459088/rails-redirect-to-new-behaviour-with-ruby-2-2-rails-4-2)

Best regards,

Fred