# Rails redirect_to new behaviour with Ruby 2.2 / Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to upgrade from Ruby 2.0 / Rails 4.0 to Ruby 2.2 / Rails 4.2, I face a surprising error when logging into my application (based on Rails Tutorial by M. Hartl):

```
Controller: SessionsController#create 
Instruction: redirect_to root_url
Error message: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Here is the sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_login(params[:session][:login])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid login/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

Here is the routes file:

```
ODQStairs::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :requests

#static pages
  get '/help',      to: "static_pages#help"
  get '/about',     to: "static_pages#about"
  get '/contact',   to: "static_pages#contact"

#root definition
  root to: "dashboards#home"

#routes
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]  
  get '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'    , via: :get
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  resources :parameters_lists do
      resources :parameters
  end
  ...
```

I did not find anything in Rails upgrade guides regarding the redirect_to function. Your help is welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at my gems versions, I actually missed a few. 
I updated to the last versions, following gems have been installed:

```
Installing websocket 1.2.1
Installing selenium-webdriver 2.44.0
Installing bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
Installing sass 3.4.12
Installing annotate 2.6.5
Installing globalid 0.3.3
```

This solved the issue.

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem in my RSpec tests on a Rails 4.0 to 4.2 upgrade and determined that it was related to turbolinks. My Gemfile.lock had:

```
turbolinks (1.3.0)
```

I changed the turbolinks dependency line in my Gemfile to

```
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 2.5'
```

Then I upgraded the gem using the following bundler command:

```
bundle update --source turbolinks
```

It upgraded my version of turbolinks to the latest and now the redirect_to method works as expected in my tests.